# Stream Order: Strahler vs Shreve

Tags: watershed, strahler

I am writing a research paper on watershed delineation and I am looking for experiences/opinions/authoritative answers on:

**What guides a hydrologist when it comes to choosing between Strahler's (1952) or Shreve's (1996) stream ordering method?**

Does morphology play a role? Or the quality of the stream network extraction help decide?
When do I choose either of the methods?

Shreve, R. L. 1966. “Statistical law of stream numbers”. J. Geol. 74:17-37.

Strahler, A. N., (1952), “Hypsometric (Area-Altitude) Analysis of Erosional Topography”. Geological Society American Bulletin, 63: 1117-1142.

Comment: I don't feel that this question is a good fit for the site. This is a Q&A site, and we tend to avoid [Chatty, open-ended questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). There is a lot of academic literature on the comparison of [comparison Strahler and Shreve](http://scholar.google.co.in/scholar?q=comparison+Strahler+and+Shreve), and it would be very difficult to provide a correct concise answer on which is _better_

Comment: If you could specify the sense of "better" -- especially if it is made in a scientific and quantitative way -- then this question should be considered on topic here.

Comment: "better" was bad! Hope the edit agrees with the site rules!

Comment: @ Devdatta Tengshe- the literature you provided does not discuss the merits or demerits of Strahler & Shreve.